# Concurrent simulations with OpenCL on Intel Xeon Phi

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, simulation, gpgpu, xeon-phi

I am having an OpenCL application which under-utilizes the capabilities of Intel Xeon Phi.

The kernel uses a database to do some statistical calculations. Therefore, I am thinking if it is possible to add a second kernel that uses the same database and run them concurrently on Phi.

E.g to use n/2 threads for kernel 1 and n/2 threads for kernel 2 etc.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

> under-utilizes the capabilities of Intel Xeon Phi.

- under-utilizes memory? Arithmetic units? Cache? SIMD?

  - Did you profile it to pin problems?

> use n/2 threads for kernel 1 and n/2 threads for kernel 2 etc

- If kernel uses too much memory and cache is not hit, you can reduce loops' limits in the kernel so each thread works on less memory and probably hit cache more often, then apply second kernel working on remaining loops. If there are m elements per thread you could:

  - n threads (for i = 0 to m/2)   +   n threads (for i=m/2 to m)

    - similar to matrix multiplication in patches to use more cache
- vectorize kernel manually to 16-wide components such as int16 and float16.

Comment: I use the roofline model to determine the utilization and for my optimized version is roughly 16% utilization of the peak performance of Phi.

Comment: You mean, your database is bottlecking and you need to start computing as soon as first blob is received and hide memory/db operation latencies through computing? Maybe it is capable of serving 20 databases at once?